# Need description for a command to remove the contents of a folder without using ls or cd

Tags: fedora

So, I have lost 70GB worth of data on my PC. I was trying to remove the contents of a folder named "Music". What I did was `rm -rf ~/Music` and it removed everything including "Music" of course.

My questions are-

- what is the right way to remove the contents of a folder without using `ls` or `cd`?
- why did the command I ran remove everything?

Comment: This question is unclear.  You ran `rm -rf` to remove your `Music`; you want to know a better way to remove the contents of some folder, but at the same time you didn't intend to lose the (70 GB) of content in that folder.  ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you ran:

```
rm -rf ~/Music
```

you told `rm` to `-f` forcibly remove the Music directory and `-r` recursively remove any directories within it.

If you want to just remove the contents of `~/Music` but leave the directory itself intact, you should run:

```
rm -r -- ~/Music/*
```

The `~/Music/*` will expand to all of the files and directories inside `~/Music` without including the Music directory itself.

If you also want to leave the subdirectories of `~/Music` alone, you should drop the `-r` switch so:

```
rm -- ~/Music/*
```

Comment: *Note: This will still remove all your Music, but it will preserve the(now empty) Folder `~/Music`.

Comment: @rudib, that is what OP asked for right?

Comment: Yes it is, I just thought I might clarify, as he mentioned a significant dataloss (that would still occur when running this command).

Comment: Just a side note; don't use `-f` unless you absolutely have to. It's like dropping a bomb on a spider. The collateral damage potential is very high.

Comment: Bad example, you should absolutely drop bombs on spiders.  Good point though.

Comment: Is there a reason you used the double dash? It should work fine without it and may confuse readers.

Comment: @multithr3at3d, it's probably unnecessary in this command since a path is specified but I think it's good habit whenever using `rm` or many other commands with switches that can be destructive.  It says that no more switches can follow.  If you had files in a folder named `-r` for example and then did `rm *` (I don't know why people do this) in it, it would actually execute `rm -r *`.  `rm -- *` will prevent that.